# RAID 1 HDD vs SSD

Tags: raid, network-attached-storage

I would like to implement backup solution in my workstation - I do not take separate NAS server into consideration, one machine is the limit for me.

My desktop is up almost 12h per day, and it can serve as NAS server in my home.
So it would be NAS server and backup storage at the same time.

The problem I have now is to decide what storage configuration to use.
In my machine I have one 1 TB M.2 NVMe disk, and it's more that enough - at least for now.
But one disk doesn't provide any safety, so I want to create RAID 1 with w additional disks.
But the question is should I create raid with 2xHDD 2TB drives or pay a little bit more and use 2xSSD 2TB?
As I said before it will server as NAS for other devices I use at home (mainly backup).
Which solution is better in terms of data durability/safety?

Comment: I read somewhere that disk used in NAS server usually do not like being started/stopped too often as it happens in desktop PC, so that is another factor I believe in decision making.

Comment: As we make very clear on the front page this site isn't for home based questions, so please take that into consideration if you ask another question - that said I do have a question for you - how do you plan to RAID these M.2 drives? Most NVMe RAID solutions aren't very good just yet. Also if you're considering buying new HDDs please consider buying a cheap NAS as it'll be an actual backup instead of just another drive in the same machine - the later setup is seriously frowned-upon by IT professionals.

Answer (score 1):

better if you will use 2xHDD 2TB, cause it is not reasonable to use SSD for backups, even there were RAID1 of SSDs. You should use application like Macrium Reflect home to backup your existing SSD to RAID1 2xHDD 2TB and so as all other home stuff. And maybe buy spare SSD just in case to use it if your main SSD dies. You will be able to restore whole SSD with boot etc.. from backup.

Answer (score 0):

There's little reason to go with HDDs over SSD these days, unless you're trying to save money. SSDs are vastly superior in every other way, mostly importantly IOPS. If you can afford the SSDs, go for it.

Regarding your stop/start question - yes, it's a consideration. The initial spin up of the drive is going to cause the most wear/tear, and 24x7 NAS/SAN use cases doesn't worry about that nearly as much because they are rarely rebooted on the same interval that a home desktop is.